# Select part of a table for later use

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently trying to optimize my program. I have a large database which consists of data which are timestamped. The data I need to update is only data for the current day, so I don't want to search the entire database more than once to find only the entries of today. Is there a way to select something and then use it later in several different (MERGE INTO) commands?

I want to select all the data of today, then run a while loop (in java) on every single entry of data for today updating them all. So is this even possible? Or do I have to traverse the entire database for each while-loop iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a proper data caching technology, like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) in order to minimize database hits for read-heavy, slowly changing data.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be just what I was looking for :)

Comment: You're welcome. I've used `memcached` with great results.  Easy to configure, scales out nicely... good stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If you are optimizing your program and your database is timestamped. Then the first thing you can do is to create index for the timestamps field. This will reduce your query execution time because your filter criteria is related to that time-stamp field.

Comment: My database isn't really timestamped. I put data in which has an ID and a timestamp and some data associated with that timestamp. So initially the database has nothing but old dates until I put in the new dates.